# function stack image in R

Tags: r, image, raster

I would like to perform an analysis on images located in a specific folder. I use:

```
library(raster)
folder <- "C:/Users/Mezeix/Pictures/FreeVideoToJPGConverter/1 images/"
img <- list.files(folder) 
img.raster<-stack(img)
```

I started with only 1 image to check. As observed the image is well stored into "img "

[image]

But when I use the function stack(img) I have the following message:

```
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 
Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)
```

I do not understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work if you use

```
img <- list.files(folder, full.names=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

`x` argument of `stack` function takes the full path of the file, if **file[img]** is not present in current working directory.

combine the directory and file name as below to make it work.

```
img_path <- paste0(folder, img) 
img.raster<-stack(x  = img_path)
```